# Adding larg number of Buttons to UIScrollView in background thread - Buttons not visible

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiscrollview, uibutton, background-process

the user should be able to select one icon from a large number of different icons. I have created a picker dialog that allows the user to make his selection. The ViewController that is used for this picker only holds one UIScrollView. In `viewDidLoad` for each icon a button is added to the ScrollView. To select an icon the user just has to click the corresponding button...

This works fine, but the ViewController/picker needs several seconds to be displayed. This is because of the many alloc / add operations within `viewDidLoad`. Because of this I tried to move these options into a background thread. This workes fine, but the created buttons are not visible any more:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.iconsScrollView.hidden = true;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        iconContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
        iconContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        iconButtons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40);
        selectedButton = nil;

        NSArray *iconInfos = [[StoreController sharedController] allIcons];

        for (IconInfo* iconInfo in iconInfos) {
            NSString *iconName = iconInfo.name;

            UIButton *iconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            iconButton.frame = buttonRect;

            [iconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(iconSelectionClick:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [iconContainer addSubview:iconButton];
            [iconButtons setObject:iconButton forKey:iconInfo.guid];

            buttonRect.origin.x += 50;
            if (buttonRect.origin.x > 205) {
                buttonRect.origin.x = 5;
                buttonRect.origin.y += 50;
            }
        }

        iconContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.iconsScrollView.frame.size.width, ceil([iconButtons count] / 5.0) * 50);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.iconsScrollView addSubview:iconContainer];
            self.iconsScrollView.contentSize = iconContainer.frame.size;

            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            self.iconsScrollView.hidden = false;

            [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
}
```

This works (almost) without any problem:

- Picker ViewController is presented
- ActivityIndicator is visible while buttons are created
- Once all buttons are ready ActivityIndicator stops and the ScrollView becomes visible.

**Only Problem:** The Buttons are not visible. The ScrollView can be used normally (content size correct) and when I touch inside the ScrollView and hit an invisible button the click selector is called. Thus all buttons are there but not visible. Eventually after 10-15 seconds all Buttons become visible at once.

Using `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsLayout` for the View, the ScrollView, or the buttons does not change anything.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: you can effectively change the UI from the main thread only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding buttons to a subview while you aren't on the main thread.

Generally, UIKit code should only be run on the main queue.

Comment: I already tried to only create the buttons in the background thread and move the adding to the scrollView back to the main thread. The result is all the same. As far as I know all UI "interaction" (adding, removing, resizing, property change) of the existing UI has to be done in the main thread. But interacting with UI objects that are not (yet) part of the view tree should be not problem, should it?

Comment: Ok, and what would be the correct solution to not freeze the UI?

Comment: Don't add buttons to a scrollview, use a more efficient way of presenting multiple items at the same time - something like a collection view.

Answer (score 0):

UIKit can only be updated from the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
});
```